# if S and T are both one-to-one, show that ST is one-to-one

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

Given V   t-> W   s-> U: 
if S and T are both one-to-one, show that ST is one-to-one.

I know that (S.T)(x)=(S.T)(y) for some x,y∈Rn. But I don't know how to apply it here. I'm lost

Answer (score 0):

If we have $S(T(x))=S(T(y))$ using that $S$ is one-to-one, we have $T(x)=T(y)$, as $T$ is one-to-one, we have $x=y$, showing that $S \circ T$ is one-to-one.